# Energy quantization at differenet frequencies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, photoelectric-effect

An electron emits light of v1 frequency. When we say energy is quantized in this case, the minimum packet of energy would be hv1 but electron can emit 2hv1, 3hv1 and so on energy. is that correct.? Also if it releasing 2hv1, it has to release 2 packets as minimum is 1hv1 for this frequency? is that correct.?

Anther electron emits light of v2 frequency. For that electron minimum energy packet would be hv2. is that correct.?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

A photon is emmited when energy is released. For an electron to release energy, it must lose energy. The most typical situation is the electron being bounded by a nucleus' potential. In that case, the electron can "be" in an energy level of the atom.

Let's say the electron has an energy $E_2$, and it falls to a lower level with energy $E_1$, then $\Delta E = E_2 - E_1 $.

The de-excitation of the electron releases energy $\Delta E$ as electromagnetic radiation of frequency given by

$$\nu=\frac{\Delta E}{\hbar} $$

But, when this happens, **one single photon** is emitted, with frequency $\nu$, or energy $\hbar \nu$

If you want to have $2 \hbar \nu$, then you need **two electrons** falling down the level.

A single electron falls down over a certain $\Delta E$, and this is only one energy, the only possible energy (neglecting band widths and other effects). In short, if the energy difference is $\Delta E$, then there will only be one photon with that energy. Otherwise, how would the electron know if it has to emit one or two photons? No, it emits one single photon.

If you want more light, then do it with more electrons. That's how many light bulbs work.

Comment: the question was more from trying to understand the blackbody radiation spectrum. I guess where I am struggling is at a given instant, if hf energy is released one by one or at an instant  2hf energy can released too. Ofcourse 2 packets of hf can be released. But can one packet of 2hf be released.?

Comment: There are not packets of $2\hbar \nu$, but there can be packets of $\hbar\cdot(2\nu)$ if you have a double-frequency harmonic. Plus, you've got many waves of the same freq.

Comment: 1st comment makes sense. 2nd comment I am slighy confused when you say you got many waves of same frequency. in that case too, even though there are lot of them, packet from each will still be ℏν?

Comment: Yes, don't be confused: **all packets are $h\nu$**. 1) If you are measring one single frequency, but more energy, tha's because you are detecting many photons, and not just one, but every single one is $h\nu$. 2) If you have more frequencies, each one will have $E_i=h\nu_i$.

Comment: ok makes sense. thx so much

Answer (score 0):

Also from google of the hydrogen energy levels:

"
The formula defining the energy levels of a Hydrogen atom are given by the equation: E = -E0/n^2, where E0 = 13.6 eV (1 eV = 1.602×10-19 Joules) and n = 1,2,3… and so on. The energy is expressed as a negative number because it takes that much energy to unbind (ionize) the electron from the nucleus.
"

But as mentioned above we need to use the difference between any two levels traversed.  So we can get higher energies (say E4 to E1) but it is always emitted per 1 photon.

Comment: the question was more from trying to understand the blackbody radiation spectrum. I guess where I am struggling is at a given instant, if hf energy is released one by one or at an instant 2hf energy can released too. Ofcourse 2 packets of hf can be released. But can one packet of 2hf be released.? –

Comment: No, your "packet" is the photon and that's a major point about quantization. It's possible that another type of atom has a transition that has energy 2x greater than say hydrogen say E3 to E2, but it would be a single photon/packet of twice the frequency and also half the wavelength. IR photons are lower energy than visible ones, and they are not so much atomic transitions but transitions from energy levels in a molecule (like CO2), the orbitals are complicated, stretched out over multiple atoms and the vibrations of the bonds are involved.